# Conformal map that fixes 2 points on upper half-lane

Tags: complex-analysis, fixed-points

Lets denote the upper half-plane by $\mathbb{H}$ and the ball centered at origin as $\mathbb{D}$. My question is what is wrong with my reasoning because I think something should be wrong but I can't catch what it is. Let me write it down.

Automorphisms of upper half plane are given by
$$h(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d} \ \ \ \text{where} \ \ \ ad-bc>0$$ These are called bilinear transformations (with $ad-bc\neq 0$) in general.

We also know from Bak & Newman *Proposition 13.19* that

- A bilinear transformations (other than the identity mapping $f (z) = z$)
  has at most two fixed points.

I've also proved that if an analytic map from  $\mathbb{D}$ to $\mathbb{D}$ has 2 distinct fixed points then it is identity. ( *Chapter 8 Exercise 12 Stein-Shakarchi Complex-Analysis* )

Here is where the problem begins. We can map $\mathbb{H}$ to $\mathbb{D}$ using the conformal map
$$ F(z)=\frac{i-z}{i+z}$$
Now suppose $G$ is an automorphism (conformal map with same domain and range) that fixes 2 points, $z_1,z_2$, on $\mathbb{H}$. Using $F$ we can construct a new automorphism $F\circ G\circ F^{-1} :\mathbb{D}\to \mathbb{D}$. This again fixes 3 points, since
$$(F\circ G\circ F^{-1})(F(z_{1,2}))=F(z_{1,2}) $$
But by the exercise I proved, the map $F\circ G\circ F^{-1}$ is identity. This means
\begin{align}
&F\circ G\circ F^{-1}(z)=z \\
\implies &F\circ G(z)= \frac{i-z}{i+z} \\
\implies &\frac{i-G(z)}{i+G(z)}= \frac{i-z}{i+z}
\end{align}
Which means $G(z)=z$. But if this is the case, why wouldn't they just say a bilinear transformation has at most **one** fixed point.

Comment: You have proved that an automorphism of $\Bbb H$ has at most two fixed points (in $\Bbb H$). Where is the problem? – If $h(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ fixes $z_1, z_2 \in \Bbb H$ then it also fixes their conjugates in the lower half-plane, i.e. it has *four* fixed points as a Möbius transformation.

Comment: note that fixed points of automorphisms of $\mathbb H$ are conjugate so they are either real or one in $\mathbb H$ and one outside of it; this is exactly what happens for the circle, automorphisms have either two fixed points on the boundary or one in, one out; this doesn;t contradict the other statement since that talks about fixed points of bilinear transformations in the extended plane, so those do not need to be in $\mathbb H$ or inside the circle in the cases when those are respective automorpshims there (and indeed both cannot be, but one can be)